# Does Apache Ignite support 10 thousands of cache?

Tags: java, caching, benchmarking, ignite

We are evaluating Apache Ignite for our product. In our scenario, we may have 10000 caches, and I have a try in the yardstick benchmark framework. I find that when the cache numbers climb to 8192, the Ignite server became abnormal. The case is expected to be finished after 1 minute since I have set the duration in the configuration, but the test keep running in 10 minutes long and I have to kill the test.

If I set the cache number to 4096, the test finished in 1 minute as expected.
So the question: Does Apache Ignite support 10 thousands of cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One cache will use around 20M heap for its data structures (per node). Multiple that by 10000 and you have 200G right here. In practice Java will not work with that much heap.

Why do you need 10,000 caches anyway? Please consider at least using Cache Groups. The best approach will be having a few caches and routing between them.

Comment: But I have checked the process's memory cost, only about 50 GB is used, and my test machine have 256 GB memory.

Comment: Normally JVM's heap usage is capped at 32G due to use of compressed pointers. You may want to disable those and retry with some heroic -Xmx (such as -Xmx192G) but results may vary,

Comment: Thanks for your reminding with Cache Groups, can I create a Cache in a specific Cache Groups in a programming way ?  We need to create Cache dynamically so the [doc](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-groups) here don't help much.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use `cacheCfg.setGroupName()` in runtime.

Comment: Thanks , the cache group does work. I am wondering that if there are any drawbacks of cache group instead of single caches?

Comment: There might be performance considerations for some bulk operations. I'm not sure since it's a rare feature to see in the wild.

Comment: Thanks so much, I see that there are about 30% performance downgrade for read operations, when compared 1 cache with 8192 caches.